# How to pass this object to concatMap mapping function?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building Angular2 module for caching images. I'm using provider service which returns Observables of loaded resources, either sync if they are already cached or async if not.

I tried however to preload batch of images on app start and ran into problem with concatMap function.

```
public preloadImages(imgUrls: string[]) {
    console.log(this.cachedResources); //Everything is fine here
    return Observable.from(imgUrls).concatMap(this.getImage);
}
```

My provider uses collection object `private cachedResources: DictMap<CachedResource>;` to store cached data, which is inaccessible from `getImage` function if it's called by concatMap.

```
public getImage(imgUrl: string) {
    console.log(this.cachedResources); //Unidentified
}
```

So how can I make it visible in function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concatMap` return un observable and its callback must return a inner Observable

```
 public preloadImages(imgUrls: string[]) {
        console.log(this.cachedResources); //Everything is fine here
        return Observable.from(imgUrls).concatMap(url=> Observable.of(this.getImage(url));
    }
```

Comment: Ah, that's just what I needed. Thanks a lot. :)